Нужно ли ставить висячий дефис при перечислении классов "бизнес", "премиум", "эконом"?
квартиры эконом, бизнес, премиум класса (или классов?)
или
квартиры эконом-, бизнес-, премиум-класса
В интернете на своих сайтах все пишут кто во что горазд - кавычки, дефис, просто. А как все-таки правильно, есть ли определяющее правило?

Квартиры бизнес-класса, премиум-класса, экономкласса. Это словарный материал. Сложные слова и сложносокращенное слово. Класс - основное понятие, поэтому оно склоняется, а остальные - приложения.   Русский орфографический словарь
премиум-класс, -а   https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=премиум-класс&mode=slovari

Совсем неправильно будет сначала перечислить классы, а потом добавить слово "класса" (или "классов")?

Совсем неправильно? Ну тогда Розенталь:  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=483. При сочетании с помощью союза и двух и более сложных существительных с одинаковой второй частью эта часть может приводиться только при последнем слове, а при предшествующих словах вместо нее пишется так называемый висячий дефис: вагоно- и паровозостроение (ср.: вагоностроение и паровозостроение), газо- и электросварка, радио- и телепередачи; авто-, мото- и велогонки.

Квартиры премиум-, бизнес- и экономкласса.  Пойдет?  Класса, но не классов.

Да, поняла, спасибо огромное!

Спасибо вам за активность на форуме) Голос от меня.

бизнес-, премиум- и элитного класса - в таком случае будет класса или классов?

Здесь, вероятно. не стоит применять такую запись, она не укладывается в норму. Ну это я так думаю)

О висячем дефисе
Это сокращенная запись исходного перечисления, при этом надо учитывать написания отдельных слов и словосочетаний по словарю (слитно, раздельно, дефис).
РЕШЕНИЕ

Исходное словосочетание: Квартиры экономкласса, бизнес-класса и премиум-класса.

Сокращенная запись:
Квартиры эконом-, бизнес- и премиум-класса.
Или: Квартиры бизнес-, премиум- и экономкласса.
Здесь используется ед. число.

Квартиры бизнес-, премиум- и элитного классов. Здесь используется мн. число (по ответам Грамоты.ру).

ТЕОРИЯ

Розенталь. Предметный указатель слов: дефис висячий http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=83

В частности: В терминологических сочетаниях используется в этих случаях так называемый висячий дефис: агрономы- и механизаторы-хлопководы (т. е. агрономы-хлопководы и механизаторы-хлопководы;

Ответы Справочной службы

В частности
№ 306678 Записывайтесь к врачу на очный или онлайн-приём…
№ 296150  Тощий бетон бывает мелко- и крупнозернистым.
№ 281581 Висячий дефис нужен: видео- и фотосъемка.
№ 249090  Необходим висячий дефис: сообщения в аудио-, видео- и текстовом форматАХ.
№ 234396 Нужен  висячий дефис при аббревиатурах-приложениях: РВ- и ТВ-техника.
№ 222356 Используется висячий дефис: водо- и ветронепроницаемость.

Еще появился вопрос на тему "класса" или "классов". Может ли быть так, что "классов" применимо в значении слова "класс" как собрание индивидуумов - типа школьный класс; класс растения, класс животные. А именно как класс в значении "уровень" должно употребляться в единственном числе?

В словаре 5 значений для слова класс, но во всех значениях есть ед. и мн. число, иначе это отдельно указывается.  4. Степень, уровень, в зависимости от которых определяется место предмета в ряду других подобных.  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=класс&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42
